# AWS CloudFormation CI CD pipeline field due Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have created AWS CI-CD pipeline. Everything ok still Staging. At of cloud formation stack creation, its failed due below error. I have given all the necessary permissions.

```
"latestExecution": {
  "errorDetails": {
    "code": "JobFailed",
    "message": "Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 82224F63323206E1; S3 Extended Request ID: repn5Zuf5TjdrLU/FVkmJeHArzF8KO46mFn4nGbjeSMnAV0gDaXvHSn8bHcy0uLoauKWcjitgLY=)"
  },
  "lastStatusChange": 1.53674421465E9,
  "status": "Failed"
}
```

Comment: See if the file exists in s3

Comment: I don't know why this throws me an error. I have given all rights. Artifacts are created inside s3 bucket.